# Is there a way to check if an action is used in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, resharper

I'd like to know if there is a way to find defunct action methods on controllers.  I have R# and ran analysis, but it didn't seem to check if the asp code called an action. Is there anything that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a tool what not know what actions are required, as they are invoked by the routing configuration. I suppose you could write a tool which could check which actions are accessible given the current routing configuration, but then it wouldn't be able to know if those methods wouldn't potentially be used by other code, as they are marked as public.

Comment: Well in this case only code in the project would reference the actions.  But that is what I was afraid of. I suppose a simple grep to see if the action name in any file would be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Implement a global action filter that records the action name in a persistent store somewhere.  This way you can track which actions do get executed and figure out what's missing from possible actions.  It's a bit tedious but may work for your purposes.